# Leer un archivo de excel con laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-excel

Necesito sacar las filas/campos de un archivo que subo de `excel` a mi proyecto laravel, realicé el código de cargar a mi base de datos directamente con `laravel excel 3.1`, pero lo que necesito es sacar los datos para luego ingresarlos yo por medio de un `insert` en la parte de los `values`. Además en el `excel` van varios datos (varias filas). Entonces ¿ Cómo se podría elaborar ese `insert` ?

Agrego el código de mi controlador (import):

```
namespace App\Imports;

 use App\tbl_instrumentos;
 use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class InstrumentosImport implements ToModel
 {

public function model(array $row)
{
    return new tbl_instrumentos([
        'ins_codigo'   => $row[0],
        'ins_observacionInicial'   => $row[1],
        'ins_claseOexactitud'    => $row[2],
    ]);
 }
}
```

Adicionalmente agrego el código de mi controlador principal:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{

public function importExportView()
{
   $data=DB::table('tbl_instrumentos')->orderBy('ins_id','DESC')
            ->get();
    return view('importar',compact('data'));
}

/**
* @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
*/
public function exportExcel($type) 
{
    return Excel::download(new InstrumentosExport, 'instrumentos.'.$type);
}

/**
* @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
*/
public function importExcel(Request $request) 
{
   $this->validate($request, [
  'select_file'  => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx'
 ]);
    Excel::import(new InstrumentosImport,$request->import_file);

     return back()->with('success', 'Datos Excel Importados Satisfactoriamente.');
}
```

El import_file que tengo en mi controlador (import) viene de mi vista por medio de un input el cual es el siguiente:

```
    <input type="file" name="import_file" />
```

Comment: Puedes *convertir un excel a CSV*, este es un fichero de texto plano, fácil de leer con PHP. Al generar el CSV los campos se separan (generalmente con comas) y los datos quedan en líneas. Lo habitual sería un CSV, donde la primera línea sean las cabeceras de columna del excel antiguo y las líneas sucesivas los datos de cada una de las celdas de la línea para esas columnas... algo de trabajo con arrays y cadenas y ya lo tienes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando un poco la documentación, tu utilizas la importación a modelo, podrías hacer un insert con query builder tal cómo ahora creas un modelo:

```
namespace App\Imports;

 use App\tbl_instrumentos;
 use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class InstrumentosImport implements ToModel
 {

public function model(array $row)
{
    DB::table('Tu_Tabla')->insert([
        'columna' => 'valor'
        ...    
    ]);
 }
}
```

Pero realmente viendo el caso de uso que quieres deberías valorar usar la importación de una colección ([import to collection](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/collection.html)).

De tal forma que tu ejemplo sería:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Imports;

use App\tbl_instrumentos;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class InstrumentosImport implements ToModel {

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        // Opcion 1, mass assignement con eloquent:
        $preparedCollection = $this->prepareCollection($rows);
        tbl_instrumentos::insert($preparedCollection);

        // Opcion 2, con queryBuilder insertando row by row (tambien puedes hacer mass assignement):
        $preparedCollection->each(static function ($row){
            DB::table('Tu_tabla')->insert($row);
        })

    }

    private function prepareCollection(Collection $collection)
    {
        return $collection->map(static function($row){
            return [
                'columna' => $row['key']
                ...
            ];
        });
    }
}
```